# query_posts() on wordpress does not show on 'order'

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to show posts in DESC order from the latest posts. I have been using `query_posts()` to get posts.But i am not getting the desired result from the query . I am using :

```
<?php 
   query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'testimonials', 'showposts' => 100, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
   if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
```

Am i doing any wrong?

Comment: can you specify what are you getting with above code ?

Comment: This code looks correct.  I suspect your issue is elsewhere.  Which date do you expect it to sort by? This is going to sort by the "published" date of the post, and it will NOT include future-dated posts.